# Why don't 8086 use 20-bit registers?

Tags: cpu-registers, x86-16

I know that 8086 has a 20-bit address bus and 16-bit registers, so it need 2 registers to locate the obsolutely memory address. Why don't 8086 use 20-bit registers?

Comment: compatibility with 8080 & 8088 (note that there's a wiki for this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several reasons.

1. it maintains some backward compatibility with the 8080.  If you set all the segment registers to 0, I *think* it will run 8080 code.
2. the data bus is only 16 bits wide.  The segmented architecture allows you to pull in a whole address in one memory read cycle.  20 bit addresses would require two.

Those are the two I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: It doesn't run 8080 code, but the instructions have equivalent-in-meaning with enough detail that the binary code can be transcoded automatically, or an assembler programmed to read 8080 source but generate the opcodes for 8086.

Comment: re: 8086 asm *source* compat with 8080: [Why are first four x86 GPRs named in such unintuitive order?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5121) / [The start of x86: Intel 8080 vs Intel 8086?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6500).  There were some assemblers that read 8080 source and emitted 8086 machine code, i.e. translating on the fly on a per-instruction basis to usually a single 8086 instruction, because 8086 was designed to make this possible.